# Filter by dimension member only without sub-nodes

Tags: ssas, mdx

I need to query a cube by a ragged dimension (parent-child).  The filter can be multiple nodes at any level.

This works in that it restricts the results to just the 2 supply chains I want...

```
SELECT    [Measures].[Total Revenue] ON COLUMNS
        , [Product].[Products].Members ON ROWS
FROM    myCube
WHERE 
(
    {
      [Supply Chain].[SupplyChains].&[{c0c62bda-0369-4591-be85-3a7078bc3352}]
    , [Supply Chain].[SupplyChains].&[{aca836e9-22ac-4952-8809-3f50aeda6891}]
    }
)
```

I know, guid keys, not my design!  The problem is that data that isn't assigned to a specific supply chain is assigned to the top node.  If I add the top node to the list, then all data will be returned (since all data is subordinate to it).

Is there a way to return values with a specific member and ignore its children?  I'd like to say "return all data assigned exactly to the top node or to the listed supply chains and their children).

Comment: Does the `DESCENDANTS` function help?

Comment: Unfortunately no...at least not the way I tried.  I tried to say in the WHERE clause something like WHERE (EXCEPT(descendants(root), {descendants(nodeIDontWant1), descendants(nodeIDontWant2)}) to try and be left with all nodes except the ones i want to filter out.  But all results were returned... I assume that since the top node was there, it still returned all sub-nodes instead of a key match

Comment: Maybe the `DataMember` property can help, similar to this post: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/775b315e-5cd8-4aec-8904-eb727ac9bd7e/mdx-datamember-in-parentchild-fact-dimension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks FrankPI, your comment pointed me in the right direction.

I ended up replicating the query in Excel and then examining the generated MDX using the OLAP PivotTable Extensions.  Excel allows you to set filters on sub-nodes like what I was trying to do.

What it does is create a set of all nodes that don't have filtered sub-nodes to get everything else.  Then for the parents of the nodes with filtered sub-nodes (and all its parents up to the root) it adds to the set those nodes but with the .DataMember function so that only the node value is included (but not its sub nodes).  So basically instead of saying what NOT to get, it explicitly says what TO get, listing all other nodes which can be a bit cumbersome but works.